# Linq to objects, joining to collections and simplify select new

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

I need some help to simplify a linq query. I have 2 classes Invoice and Customer. 
The Invoice have a property CustomerId and a property Customer.
I need to get all invoices and include the Customer object.
I don't like my query, as it needs to change if new properties are added to the Invoice object.
I can't join the invoice and customer earlier than this stage so that is not an alternative.

My query.

```
var customers = GetCustomers();
var invoices = GetInvoices();
var joinedList = (from x in invoices
                  join y in customers on x.CustomerId equals y.CustomerId
                  select new Invoice
                  {
                     Amount = x.Amount,
                     CustomerId = x.CustomerId,
                     Customer = y,
                     InvoiceId = x.InvoiceId
                   }).ToList();
```

The classes

```
   public class Invoice
   {
      public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
      public double Amount { get; set; }
      public int CustomerId { get; set; }
      public Customer Customer { get; set; }
   }

   public class Customer
   {
      public int CustomerId { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   private static IEnumerable<Invoice> GetInvoices()
   {
         yield return new Invoice
         {
            Amount = 34,
            CustomerId = 1,
            InvoiceId = 1
         };
         yield return new Invoice
         {
            Amount = 44.7,
            CustomerId = 1,
            InvoiceId = 2
         };
         yield return new Invoice
         {
            Amount = 67,
            CustomerId = 2,
            InvoiceId = 3
         };
         yield return new Invoice
         {
            Amount = 89,
            CustomerId = 3,
            InvoiceId = 4
         };
      }

      private static IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
      {
         yield return new Customer
         {
            CustomerId = 1,
            Name = "Bob"
         };
         yield return new Customer
         {
            CustomerId = 2,
            Name = "Don"
         };
         yield return new Customer
         {
            CustomerId = 3,
            Name = "Alice"
         };
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just a simple `foreach` loop:

```
// Dictionary for efficient look-up
var customers = GetCustomers().ToDictionary(c => c.CustomerId);
var invoices = GetInvoices().ToList();

//TODO: error checking
foreach(var i in invoices)
    i.Customer = customers[i.CustomerId];
```